# Windows Git won't work correctly with ConEMU after updating both

Tags: windows-7, bash, git, conemu

I had a working workflow with Git on my Windows 7 using ConEMU.
I upgraded my Git and my ConEMU to their latest versions this weekend.
I don't remember exactly which versions I had installed before (Not that old, this Windows install is from January 2). I don't have to original install files anymore from when I installed both.

When I now run `git pull|fetch|push` I get the following error:

[image]

Things like `git status` etc work fine.

I use the following config for my ConEmu Git terminal
[image]

Currently running the following software

- ConEmu 180131 [64]
- Git for Windows v2.16.1(2)
- Windows 7 SP1

How do I get my nice workflow back? Googling the error code gives my no new info, everyone is having problems with large tags etc. 
But Git does work correctly when I open the Git bash shortcut in the start menu, no problem using pull/fetch/push then. But then it opens its own window and it skips ConEMu entirely, which is is annoying if you're used to have 4-8 terminals open at the same time.

Comment: "error: cannot spawn git" Whatever shell is generating that error message is the source of the problem. Is Git still on your PATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's related to ConEmu.

- Close all consoles completely, ensure there are no ConEmu processes are running, start terminal.
- If previous step doesn't help, try to restart your PC and reinstall Git.
- Try to run ConEmu from `Win+R` as following: `ConEmu64.exe -basic -run {git bash}`.
- At last, run `git-bash.exe` without ConEmu. If it doesn't work, you shall go on the git-for-windows issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks. I tried all the things you suggested, and then went to the git-for-windows issue tracker. Where I promptly found this current bug:
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1475
I'm going to downgrade my git. Thanks for suggesting that, it solved my problem for now!